# Find Customer id whose Order Status never fails

Tags: mysql, sql

Order Table

| order_id | cust_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| o1 | c1 | S |
| o2 | c1 | S |
| o3 | c2 | F |
| o4 | c2 | F |
| o5 | c3 | F |
| o6 | c3 | S |

I want sql query for loyal customer.
Customer whose order naver fail is loyal customer. I just need customer ids.

Select cust_id from Order...

Answer (score 1):

```
Select cust_id 
  from Order 
  group by cust_id
  having count(case when status = 'F' then 1 else null end) =0
```

Comment: It will give o6 record also.. Output of query i required is only o1 and o2 record. All status must Success.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a separate list of customers, then you can use `not exists`:

```
select c.cust_d
from customers c
where not exists (select 1
                  from orders o
                  where o.cust_id = c.cust_id and o.status = 'F'
                 );
```

When using subqueries, I strongly strongly recommend `NOT EXISTS` over `NOT IN`.  `Not in` does not do what you expect when the subquery returns a `NULL` value.  There might be no `NULL`s in this case, but eventually you will have a hard-to-debug problem if you use `NOT IN`.

Comment: I dont have separate list but thanks for your query. I got hint. Please check below answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks  @Gordon Linoff for hint.

Select cust_id from order where status not in
( Select cust_id from order where status ='F')